# Собрать массив из уже имеющего

Tags: php

Есть такой массив

```
Array
(
    [chat_111] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47
            [1] => 1
        )

    [chat_110] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47
            [1] => 3
        )

    [chat_1167] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Как с него создать новый массив такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [47] => [4]

    [32] => [3]
)
```

Вот на картинке ниже попитался схематически показать что я пробую сделать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [47] => [4] -  где [4] это общее количество значений 47 ?

Comment: @Arsen да, это общее количество значений. А 47 Это уникальный id

Comment: Значит у вас в исходном массиве всегlа только [0] и [1]

Comment: @Arsen, да все верно. Только  [0] и [1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть в том, чтобы пройти по массиву циклом, и на каждой итерации проверять наличие ключей - если такой ключ есть в массиве, добавляем к его значению значение текущего ключа, а если ключа в массиве нет - добавляем пару ключ=>значение. Пример:

```
$array = [
    'chat_111' =>  [
        47,
        1
    ],

    'chat_110' => [
        47,
        3
    ],

    'chat_1167' =>  [
        32,
        3
    ],
];

$out = [];

foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ( (array_key_exists($a[0], $out)) !== false ) {
        $out[$a[0]] += $a[1];
    } else {
        $out[$a[0]] = $a[1];
    }
}

var_dump($out);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  47 => int 4
  32 => int 3
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. С array_key_exists знаком в мислях понимал что нужно так сделать, но сам код написать никак не мог.